# ansible module stop and start service ssh

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-module

I am trying to clear a hands on in HackerRank, where the task is to stop and start the service named ssh using service module. I have used the below code.

```yaml
- name: "Stop ssh"
  service:
    name: ssh
    state: stopped
- name: "start ssh"
  service:
    name: ssh
    state: started
```

Can you please guide me to clear the hands on.

Comment: I think you are looking for `restarted` instead of a stop/start

Comment: i am supposed not to use restarted and also with_items iterator. Thanks for your response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/13581974/carlito-15  can you please help me to clear the handson

Answer (score 1):

The service handling ssh on Linux is called `sshd` like a lot of other services, where the `d` stands for [*daemon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)).

So your correct tasks would be:

```yaml
- name: Stop ssh
  service:
    name: sshd
    state: stopped
- name: Start ssh
  service:
    name: sshd
    state: started
```

This said, since Ansible connects through ssh, I am unsure how this will really react when the service is stopped.

Most of the linux services, though do also have a `restart` instruction, that you can also use in Ansible, with the [`state` value `restarted`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html#parameter-state).

```yaml
- name: Restart ssh
  service:
    name: sshd
    state: restarted
```